# Why should not declare const variable in export default line in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have declared const variable like,

```
"student.js"
 export default const mark= 20;
```

I am Calling this constant in index.js file

```
"index.js"
import {mark} from './student';
console.log("Mark Value ::::" + mark);
```

am getting error????

Comment: *am getting error????* You are asking or telling?

Comment: import mark  from './student';

Comment: it wont work . am asking the reason.

Comment: `export default` means you are exporting a module. `export const` means you are exporting part of a module and module will be formed later after combining all exports. So you should get error on `export default const` itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`export default` [expects an expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Syntax). While `const` is a statement.

You can't do `export default const mark = 20` for the same reason you can't do `console.log(const mark = 20)`.

If `mark` isn't used anywhere else in this file, it should be:

```
export default 20;
```

Otherwise it should be:

```
const mark = 20;
export default mark;
```

And imported like:

```
import mark from './student';
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @estus answer, for your code to work change as follows.

"student.js"

```
export const mark = 20;
```

"index.js"

```
import {mark} from './student';
console.log("Mark Value ::::" + mark);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking this question. I will try like this way.:)

Answer (score 0):

What happens on `export default var a = 10, b = 20, c = 30`?

Check out [this discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-export-default-var-a-1-invalid-syntax).